# How to create a scrollable template using fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to achieve something like following

[image: Wireframe vertical layout. Search bar fragment, Banner Slider, Items Fragment]

I am trying to build an activity joining 3 fragments. Top fragment contains a search bar (`EditText`), middle fragment has a Banner Slider (`ViewPager`), and the bottom fragment contains a `GridView` loaded with `n` number of items dynamically. I want to make the middle & bottom fragments scrollable vertically while the top one being fixed. But the Grid view is scrolling within itself while the height is set to `wrap_content`.

If the `GridView` is given a fixed height, it is working as expected. But I cannot give it a fixed height as its content is dynamically loaded.

**Home Activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerSearchBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerPopularItems"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>      

</RelativeLayout>
```

**SearchBarFragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomeSearchBarFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="2dp"
        android:paddingVertical="2dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSearchBoxHome"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_search_home"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:hint="@string/home_searchbox_hint"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Banner Slider Fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomePromoSliderFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Popular Items Fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragments.HomePopularItemsFragment">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gvPopularItems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="150dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
        </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take nestedScrollView outside of ViewPager and Gridview.

Set the recycler View to **setNestedScrollingEnable(false)**.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </GridView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: No luck! Now it does not scroll at all unless I set a fixed height for GridView!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using `Constraint Layout` for whole layout, `autocomplete text view` for search bar, `viewpager` for banners, recycler view for showing the loaded items.

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

** Set the margins as per the UI

```
Set your layout manager as Gridlayout manager for recycler view as below:

recyclerview.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false)
```

Hope it will work fine. Let me know if you find any issues.